# How to exclude unique value

Tags: ldap

Objects (Users) in an LDAP directory have a multi-valued alphanumeric attribute “Profile”. I need a search filter that returns every User that has any Profile, other than P0 (regardless of whether or not the User has P0). For example:

User1 has P0 only
User2 has P1 only
User3 has P2 and P0

The search should return User2 and User3. Can this be done by a filter alone (no scripts)?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

based on provided information then your answer to the Question of

> "The search should return User2 and User3. Can this be done by a
>   filter alone (no scripts)?"

is No.

Comment: Tested, doesn't work. The "not equal" part excludes everyone with P0, even if they have other Profiles.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to ask if an object has a value "other than" something, and there is no way to ask for objects that have more than 1 value set.

You might be able to approach it from the other way: ask for objects which have any of the other profiles:

```
(|(profile=P1)(profile=P2))
```

Another way that *might* work is to use the `>=` and `<=` operators. However, this is tricky because they include equality - there are no `>` or `<` operators in LDAP. These comparisons are done lexicographically (the order the characters appear in the ASCII chart). This will be much easier if all these profile names end in numbers, like your example. But it would be very tricky to do otherwise.

For example, if you know all profiles end with a number, and you want to find objects that have a profile other than `P0`, you can do this:

```
(profile>=P00)
```

Lexicographically, every number will come after `00`. This is an easy example, since `P0` will be the lowest you could go. But if you wanted to find objects that had anything other than `P5` for example, then you'd have to have a `<=` condition too:

```
(|(profile<=P49)(profile>=P50))
```

If your profiles are names and do not all end with numbers, it will get trickier, but might still be able to do it. For example, if you want to find objects with a profile other than `PurpleProfile`, then this should work:

```
(|(profile<=purpleprofild~)(profile>=purpleprofile\20))
```

The `<=` condition changes the last character to the one before and adds a `~`, the last visible character on the ASCII chart. The `>=` condition adds a space at the end (escaped), which is the first visible character on the ASCII chart.

The goal here is to make sure you're not excluding any values that would get sorted between the values you choose here and the value you want to exclude. I used the option in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to sort lexicographically (highlight everything, then Edit -> Line Operations -> Sort Lines Lexicographically Ascending) to test this out with various values. You might have to do the same.

The only other way is to query for objects that have any profile set with `(profile=*)` and do additional checks after you get the results back and discard the ones you don't want. However, this can hurt the performance of your application if you're doing this often.

Comment: There are 10,000 different values in the Profile attribute and they change daily. So listing them explicitly in the filter is not an option. This query is a part of of a commercial off the shelf application to allow users access. Unfortunately the application does not have an option to tweak the results of the query.

Comment: @safesphere I added another option that might work for you, but it's not clean.